# Classic ASP vs PHP for a new web app

Tags: asp-classic

I am about to make a new Web application. My PHP skills are a little above average - I would'nt put myself under enterprise level coding. However my Classic ASP skills are strong and I have programmed VB in Classic ASP before for powerful websites.

I am going to make a ad network market place - buying and selling ad space online. It would be CDN backed with CDN JS and CDN image distribution with DNS and load balanced mySQL cluster servers.

What are everyones thoughts? I take it, Nginx can't run Windows?

Classic ASP to note, IMO, still handles and performs well on some sites. My concern is for future and speed and performance. Security on Classic ASP and PHP - well, Classic ASP with VB wins for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The question invites a pretty subjective answer. However, I'll try to be objectively subjective.

Since 5.3, PHP is the best choice in my opinion.

Also, if you're really intending to build it for scalability, I'd suggest looking at a cloud service like Amazon Web Services for your server (EC2), CDN (S3 + CloudFront) and database (RDS). If you're considering going as far as using Nginx there are some good configuration options at http://scalr.net/ for working with a few different clouds, including AWS.

Comment: I am going to be using Rackspace Cloud - but the arguement here is, if it works, then why change it. ASP Classic works and it can work well and powerful. I have done some things on things on the code that still impress me how they perform today with peak traffic.

Comment: Well, like I said, it's subjective. If you love ASP Classic then no one will be able to make you hate it.I think it comes down to practicality and taking the wider view. If you're using ASP Classic you'll be missing out on a lot of the benefits you could be getting from other technologies which are supported by a community of developers and services.

Comment: Scalr is a service layer that helps you get more benefit from using a cloud host like AWS. They have configurations for creating instances that are pre-configured with Nginx, Apcahe, MySQL etc, for handling load balancing, DNS etc. Basically the kind of infrastructure and processes that go hand in hand with Continuous Integration and automated deployment in general. They also support Rackspace I believe. Another one is Rightscale, but I found them much harder the get started with.

Comment: I have apps that are running SAAS on Windows servers... websites interfaced with Microsoft Word and other Windows software. Those apps will not run on a Linux server and it would be a total waste of resources trying to run PHP on a Windows server just to play with what is not better than Classic ASP at all. Classic ASP is simpler to code, more logical and it may be older than the latest versions of PHP, but that is how good it still is after all these years.

Answer (score 6):

Even if you know Classic ASP better than PHP - Classic ASP is obsolete [for nearly ten years](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASP.NET):

> It [ASP.NET] was first released in January 2002 with version 1.0 of the .NET Framework, and is the successor to Microsoft's Active Server Pages (ASP) technology.

I wouldn't start a new project with a technology that is ten years obsolete.

I don't know if Nginx runs on Windows, but it's definitely possible to run PHP and mySQL on Windows. There are Windows installers for mySQL, and [it's even possible to run PHP on IIS](http://php.iis.net/).

Comment: Ten years obsolete by whom? Those who cannot afford a descent Windows server? I have applications written in Classic ASP that are far more sophisticated than anything that has ever been written in PHP.

Answer (score 3):

Why is this even a question? Classic ASP is obsolete. When do you expect the next version of Classic ASP? When do you expect even the next *patch*?

Now, ask yourself the same questions about PHP.

To paraphrase an old "TV Guide" advertisement, "Get it? Got it? Good.".

I would recommend neither of the two, and would go with ASP.NET MVC. It's closer in pattern to Classic ASP, and I believe you can even program it in the *same* pattern - don't use a model, use a single controller that takes the view name as a parameter, and do all the work in the view.

Comment: I have applications written in ASSP that you cannot write in PHP. So which is obsolete?

Comment: What's capability have to do with it? "Classic ASP" is obsolete, period. PHP is still a living thing.

Comment: If it is obsolete, how come it works better than anything else on Windows servers? And will for a long time to come. Classic ASP doesn't need patching because it was perfected in the first place.

Answer (score 3):

A lot of people still use classic ASP all the time. So if your strengths are there, go ahead and use it. I know I still have to use it every day.

That being said, if your skills are that strong in ASP, you should have no problem moving to PHP. A couple of hours with a good code book will help you get through. Here is a basic cross-reference guide to ASP and PHP.

http://www.design215.com/toolbox/asp.php

Answer (score 2):

My recommendation would be PHP, coz it scales well, has a large community support, wide variety of IDEs and editors, robust frameworks and wide spread usage as a choice web development technology. My experience with ASP was long ago and was quite cumbersome, but PHP with all the said features and more like fully OO, works nicely. PHP as of now is on steady footing in web development arena.